# How to debug binary module of nodejs?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I have a node.js module written in C++ that provides some bindings for a C++ library. The library crashes with SIGSEGV, so I need to debug it with GDB and find out what goes wrong.

I already have the source for the module in `./node_modules/somelib/` and if I go to that folder and type `npm install` the library is compiled and can be used through a require('somelib') from node.js. I can attach gdb to node and reproduce the error, but in the stacktrace I just see `node_modules/somelib/Release/somelib.node`.

I'm not sure if this is important but the library is compiled using `node-gyp`.

- **Question 1:** How do I load the source code or point gdb to the source code?
- **Question 2:** How do I configure `node-gyp` to produce debug symbols?

Comment: [This blog post](http://people.cs.vt.edu/~davisjam/blog-technical.html#node-debugging-cpp-addons) covers things, including the need to modify your `require` call from `.../Release/...` to `require('./ObjModule/build/Debug/objModule')`, as well as the steps mentioned here: `node-gyp configure --debug` and then `node-gyp build --debug -j 8`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just found the answer to this in the `node-gyp` documentation. The solution is to invoke the build process with the `--debug` flag. That means to invoke `node-gyp configure --debug` and/or `node-gyp build --debug`. Then instead of a `Release` folder a `Debug` folder will be created. gdb will then automatically load the source files.

Comment: In JS, how to require debug module? I try to require('./node_module/xxx/Debug/test.node');

Answer (score 6):

***Shamelessly copied from an [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180226112824/http://people.cs.vt.edu/~davisjam/blog-technical.html#node-debugging-cpp-addons) of the (now broken) link provided by @Peter Cordes***

First, compile your add-on using node-gyp with the --debug flag.

```
$ node-gyp --debug configure rebuild
```

Second, if you're still in "playground" mode like I am, you're probably loading your module with something like

```
var ObjModule = require('./ObjModule/build/Release/objModule');
```

However, when you rebuild using node-gyp in debug mode, node-gyp throws away the Release version and creates a Debug version instead. So update the module path:

```
var ObjModule = require('./ObjModule/build/Debug/objModule');
```

Alright, now we're ready to debug our C++ add-on. Run gdb against the node binary, which is a C++ application. Now, node itself doesn't know about your add-on, so when you try to set a breakpoint on your add-on function (in this case, StringReverse) it complains that the specific function is not defined. Fear not, your add-on is part of the "future shared library load" it refers to, and will be loaded once you require() your add-on in JavaScript.

```
$ gdb node
...
Reading symbols from node...done.
(gdb) break StringReverse
Function "StringReverse" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
```

OK, now we just have to run the application:

```
(gdb) run ../modTest.js 
...
Breakpoint 1, StringReverse (args=...) at ../objModule.cpp:49
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is incredibly useful. Shamelessly copy away!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a VSCode user, you may find this helpful inorder to debug your module.

Basic steps are:

1. Install the vscode plugin https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb
2. Setup your launch.json to look like this :

`{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
     "type": "lldb",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Program",
     "program": "/absolute/path/to/node",
     "args": [
        "/absolute/path/to/your/index.js"
     ]
  }]
}`

Then setup breakpoints as you would in VS Code.

Happy debugging!

I have also published a detailed blog here if you want more detailed explanation.

https://medium.com/@atulanand94/debugging-nodejs-c-addons-using-vs-code-27e9940fc3ad

Answer (score 0):

You can add the directory containing the source of the module to gdb's search path:

```
(gdb) directory /path/to/source
```

See: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html

Also, to get `node-gyp` debug symbols, install `node-gyp-dbg/dev` or equivalent, or compile it with `-g`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that was not it. However I already found the solution in the node-gyp documentation.