# How to attach Visual Studio to a C++ node module?

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio, debugging, node.js-addon

I wrote a node.js module in C++ with Visual Studio. I created the project with `node-gyp configure --debug`. This seems to work fine and I can compile my code and a loadable binary is created in the `Debug` folder. I am then able to `require('./build/Debug/mymodule)` this file from a `server.js` file and when I start the server from the command line (`node server.js`), the module runs. But I am struggling to figure out how to attach the Visual Studio Debugger.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228868/how-to-debug-binary-module-of-nodejs) it sounds like gdb is automatically attached (?), but how do I invoke my `server.js` with the Visual Studio debugger?

Edit: I run Visual Studio 2015 and node v4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out.

1. Goto: Project->Properties
2. Open "Debugging" options under "Configuration Properties"
3. Set path for your node.js installation and the path to your "server.js" (or whatever you called your file)
4. Start node with the green debug button directly from Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: Node should be compiled in debug mode also.
Great HOWTO: http://computer-vision-talks.com/how-to-debug-nodejs-addons-in-visual-studio/